# python multiprocessing.connection reports "AuthenticationError: digest received was wrong"

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a python application that creates a subprocess, opens a socket to communicate with it, then creates a multiprocessing.connection object over the socket. The connection object uses a shared key (randomly generated) and hmac to ensure that no other process will be allowed to communicate over the connection.

On Linux, this works perfectly. On windows, I get the error:

```
multiprocessing.AuthenticationError: digest received was wrong
```

The key is a string of randomly generated bits which is pickled before being sent to the subprocess by its stdin:

```
authkey = ''.join([chr(random.getrandbits(7)) for i in range(20)])
```

And I have checked carefully that the key matches on both ends of the connection this-a-way:

```
 print "key:", ' '.join([str(ord(x)) for x in authkey])
```

The server is started with:

```
 l = multiprocessing.connection.Listener(
         ('localhost', int(port)), authkey=authkey)
```

..and the client is started with:

```
 c = multiprocessing.connection.Client(
         ('localhost', int(port)), authkey=authkey)
```

Both processes are running on the same machine, with the same version of python.

Stranger yet, I have found that if I fix the key (say, authkey='test'), then I still get the AuthenticationError the first time I run the program, but not on subsequent runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution appears to be to use `os.urandom` to generate the key rather than the method shown above. I do not know why this has any effect--in either case we're passing random byte strings. The solution is also more correct from a security standpoint because getrandbits is not intended for cryptographic use.

Comment: Hi @Luke , how did you use `os.urandom` to generate the key? My server process and client process are distributed in two different linux machines. I got this error although they use the same string key.

Comment: It's just `authkey = os.urandom(20)`. See: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/multiprocess/processes.py#L73